# RISC-V Exceptions, Traps, interrupts and MSRs

Tags: exception, interrupt, riscv, interrupt-handling, riscv32

I am very new to RISC-V and trying to write my own simplest implementation as a project. I am aiming at the simplest option - RV32I. Currently I have consumed only the required (or so I hope) parts of the "unprivileged" document, again because I am trying to show myself how very simple it can be.

I can see that the interrupt vector implementation is open (EEI decision).
I can also see that RV32I defines software trap commands (ECALL, EBREAK).
I was originally working off the May 7 2017 version of the spec (which is BTW the first Google result I get for "risc V documentation"), and figured that trap information, specifically the return address (the one that caused the trap, or the next one) will be stored in a CSR, allowing for a proper "return from trap handler" operation.
However looking at the doc from December 23 2019, all CSR instructions were removed from the RV32I specification.

So my question is - first, am I wrong to think I can complete a standard RV32I implementation reading just the "unprivileged" document?
Moreover - given that ECALL/EBREAK are mandatory in RV32I (while it is mentioned they can have an identical implementation) and also that instructions like JAL should generate an exception on misaligned targets, evidently RV32I needs to handle trap-like operations.

How can the trap handler know the very basic data item of where the PC came from?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm in exactly the same boat as you. Did you ever get an answer? I'm no expert but as far as I can tell the trap/exception details are in the privileged spec, and implementation is mandatory, so technically you do need to read it. However unless you are actually running an OS on your chip then ECALL and EBREAK won't be used and you can just reset the chip if an exception happens. Probably not standard compliant but good enough for learning.

Comment: Hi @Timmmm. I could not get a formal answer, however I got an answer in the risc-v forum, in the comment below.
My issue with the answers there is that they say that *in reality* the unprivileged spec cannot stand for its own.
After consulting with several friends who hold expertise in the CPU field I am inclined to implement the spec as-is by using the stack to hold the required information. This is not a very common implementation but since this is an education project getting an extra angle might be a virtue, and I get to adhere to the spec firmly.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/groups.riscv.org/g/isa-dev/c/F5SZcOm1_y8/m/Arc1rML-AAAJ?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer